# Disable Visual Studio shift-escape shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-2013

I'm using VsVim in Visual Studio 2013. Occasionally, when trying to save a file after entering text in "insert" mode, I use`<ESC>:w<ENTER>`, which *usually* works, but sometimes I fat-finger it and somehow end up closing the file's tab without saving.

Googling for close-file shortcuts in Visual Studio, it looks like these sorts of shortcuts generally use `<Ctl>` plus a function key. But I'm pretty sure I'm not accidentally hitting `<Ctl>`, and I'm certain I'm not accidentally hitting a function key.

What's going on? Can this behavior be disabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally stumbled on an answer as I was writing the question, so I figured I'd finish up the question and share the answer as well to help anyone having this same problem.

This is apparently due to the [`<shift><esc>` shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31639276/1858225). Thanks to [this page](http://www.veodin.com/keyrocket/shortcut-database/visual-studio-2012-shortcuts/) (linked to in the answer that led me to `<shift><esc>`), the shortcut is called "Close Tool Window." This is incredibly annoying, because without this shortcut there would be no problem with hitting `<shift>` a little early in order to prepare for the `:`.

To disable the shortcut, go to the `Tools > Options` menu, select `Keyboard` under `Environment` from the navigation panel, search for `Window.CloseTool` (do **not** hit `<ENTER>`), and simply click `Remove`.